# Reading value from ComboBox and placing it into textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox on my form. This is linked to a table which holds a Staff name and a Staff reference for that person.

The Combobox shows all the staff names and on selection should create the value of **staffRef**, I want to be able to select the name and the **StaffRef** is populated into the textbox.

So Far, I can only get the word **StaffRef** to go in there.

Here's my code, hope you can help!

```
        Private Sub frmAddCar_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Handles MyBase.Load


        'TODO: This line of code loads data from the 'namesstolenpool' table and drops
         it into the combobox(Driver_Name).

        Dim table As DataTable
        table = BusinessData.VerifierLogic.Load("namesstolenpool", 
        New Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Driver_name.DataSource = table
        Driver_name.DisplayMember = "displayname"
        Driver_name.ValueMember = "staffref"

    End Sub

    'This should display the "value" of the combobox in the textbox. 


    Private Sub Driver_name_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object
    , e As System.EventArgs) Handles Driver_name.SelectedIndexChanged

        TextBox1.Text = Driver_name.ValueMember

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
 Private Sub Driver_name_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object
    , e As System.EventArgs) Handles Driver_name.SelectedIndexChanged

        TextBox1.Text = Driver_name.SelectedItem("staffref")

    End Sub
```